# NodeJS bug, when executing child_process.exec

Tags: exec, child-process

## What am I missing here?

I want to get results of cucumber-js process in code. In JSON format:

```js
const { exec } = require('child_process')

function getResults () {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const options = {
      encoding: 'utf8'
    };
    let results = '';
    let commands = 'cucumber-js —format json';

    const proc = exec(commands, options);

    proc.stdout.setEncoding('utf8');
    proc.stdout.on('data', chunk => { results += chunk });
    proc.stdout.on('end', () => { resolve(results) });
    proc.stdout.on('error', reject);
  })
}

getResults().then(console.log)
```

In results i get not enough stdout, and json (results) is not valid

When i change line,- all are working:

`let commands = 'cucumber-js —format json';`

==============>

`let commands = 'cucumber-js —format json > results.txt && cat results.txt';`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to play with `maxBuffer` option.

Read more: https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback

Also this code sample might be useful:

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
var child = exec('npm ls --json --long', {
    encoding: 'utf8',
    // maxBuffer Number largest amount of data (in bytes) allowed on stdout or stderr - if exceeded child process is killed (Default: 200*1024)
    maxBuffer: 10*1024*1024
});
```